# How to fix AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' if using mysql?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

Django development server was running fine using mysql up to yesterday. But today I get the error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`.

I created a new blank django instance by running `django-admin startproject newProject`. It runs with `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'`.  But produces same error when I change it to `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'`

System specification:

```
os: manjaro linux
virtual environment python version: 3.6
Django version: 2.2
MariaDB version: 10.3.15-1
```

Have not updated any related package in last 3 days.

The error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.init_connection_state()
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 232, in init_connection_state
    if self.features.is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled:
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 82, in is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled
    cursor.execute('SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL')
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
  File "/srv/http/python/env/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 147, in last_executed_query
    query = query.encode(errors='replace')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Why does your traceback have **`query.encode()`** when the actual 2.2.2 Django release uses **`query.decode()`**? That entirely invalidates my diagnosis as I had mistakenly assumed I was looking at the same code by [looking at the released version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.2/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py#L140-L147). You appear to have already altered your local Django source code, which also explains why the traceback puts the error at line 147 rather than the expected line 146.

Comment: Thank you for your help & time. I have confirmed my friend changed it while using my PC. I'm currently using
```if not isinstance(query, bytes):
query = query.encode(errors='replace')```
If there are problems I will reinstall. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank to Martijn, I have fixed this.
In the source, stable 2.2 branch line `146` of `django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py` is

`query = query.decode(errors='replace')`

In my system `path/to/virtualenv/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py` was like

```
# query = query.decode(errors='replace')
query = query.encode(errors='replace')
```

I changed it to

```
query = query.decode(errors='replace')
# query = query.encode(errors='replace')
```

It is working correctly now.

Comment: Right, so you really want to force a reinstall of Django, and everything else too if that’s been altered in-place: `pip install —force-reinstall -r requirements.txt`

Comment: And that line was probably changed in an (I’ll-informed) attempt to try and make PyMySQL work, as per https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30380. In which case you’d want to add `from django.utils.encoding import force_text` At the top and then use [`query = force_string(query)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py#L152-L157).